# Multiple input field with EasyAutocomplete - Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using [EasyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide) to select some data.

The problem I'm having is that I only can use one autocomplete input. I tried to find a solution but  I didn't find anything in the documentation.

**My code:**

```
<%= form_tag('/search', local: true, method: :get, class: 'form-group row' ) do %>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <%= text_field_tag(:q, nil, data: { behavior: 'autocomplete-lang' }, placeholder: 'Lenguaje', class: 'form-control') %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<%= form_tag('/search', local: true, method: :get, class: 'form-group row' ) do %>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <%= text_field_tag(:q, nil, data: { behavior: 'autocomplete-ide' }, placeholder: 'Lenguaje', class: 'form-control') %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
def search
    @lang = Content.ransack(name_cont: params[:q],types_id_eq: 1).result(distinct: true)
    @ide = Content.ransack(name_cont: params[:q],types_id_eq: 4).result(distinct: true)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json {
        @lang = @lang.limit(5)
        @ide = @ide.limit(5)
      }
    end
end
```

**Js:**

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    var $input = $("[data-behavior='autocomplete-lang']");


    var options = {
        getValue: "name",
        url : function(phrase) {
            return "/search.json?q=" + phrase;
        },
        categories: [
            {
                listLocation: "lang"
            }
        ],
        list: {
            onChooseEvent: function () {
                var id = $input.getSelectedItemData().id;
                console.log(id);
            }
        }
    };

    $input.easyAutocomplete(options);

});

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    var $input_ide = $("[data-behavior='autocomplete-ide']");
    //IDE
    var options_ide = {
        getValue: "name",
        url : function(phrase) {
            return "/search.json?q=" + phrase;
        },
        categories: [
            {
                listLocation: "ide"
            }
        ],
        list: {
            onChooseEvent: function () {
                var id = $input_ide.getSelectedItemData().id;
                console.log(id);
            }
        }
    };

    $input_ide.easyAutocomplete(options_ide);
});
```

So, I only can use once the `easyAutocomplete`, if I use it twice the behavior is not correct and only one input work.

I really need a hand to solve this, is must be pretty simple, but I can't get it.

Comment: You could elaborate on how "the behavior is not correct" when you try to use two.

Comment: Only one input field works

Comment: So what you're saying is that only one of the inputs shows the autocomplete dropdown? Which one?

Comment: @vijoc `autocomplete-lang`. And `console.log` shows `undefined` but if I comment `$input_ide.easyAutocomplete(options_ide);` shows the correct id

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and solved it by adding unique "id"s to each text field.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, instead of writing:

```js
getValue: "name"
```

You can write something similar to:

```js
getValue: function (element) {
    return element.lang+ element.ide
}
```

You can follow the discussion on this [github link](https://github.com/pawelczak/EasyAutocomplete/issues/256).